# angularjs: howto access directive (text) value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to write a directive that shows/hides the element based on the role I'm providing as a parameter (string value).

I have the following directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('fuse')
        .directive('showWhenRole', showWhenRoleDirective);

    /** @ngInject */
    function showWhenRoleDirective(auth) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                showWhenRole: '@'
            },
            compile: function(scope, tElement) {
                console.log("showWhenRoleDirective",scope.showWhenRole);
                // if (auth.isAdmin()) {
                //     tElement.show();
                // } else {
                //     tElement.hide();
                // }
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

My HTML element looks as follows:

```
<md-menu-bar id="user-menu" show-when-role="admin">
```

When I look in the console, the message is:

```
showWhenRoleDirective undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the value of `admin` a boolean value on your scope or is this a string value you need to check against.  I'm assuming it's a string value because you've defined the isolate scope with the `@` assignment.

Comment: Good question. Its a string value, hence I used the '@' in the scope section

Comment: also, why aren't you using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`?

Comment: move from `compile` to `link`, scope is not available in compile phase. also check scope/$scope

Comment: because then I have to an equation statement... And I want to abstract the implementation from the views....

Comment: ahhhh good catch @entre.  Yeah you need this to be inside the `link` function, the $scope is not available in the compile phase.

Comment: Assuming moving from compile to link doesnt solve the problem, can you just post the code where you register this directive? In case the directive is cool but the registration is failing.

Comment: @SanderSpilleman try `<md-menu-bar id="user-menu" show-when-role="'admin'">`

Comment: modified post to include full code. registration is ok though, otherwise I wouldnt get the output from console.log

Comment: Moving to link fn did the trick! Thanks!!!

Comment: @SanderSpilleman i will put comment as answer.. please accept it

Answer (score 1):

move from `compile` to `link`, `scope` is not available in `compile` phase